# Jquery making variables from elements inside of "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have 4 blocks, each with the same wrapper class. Inside of each of these blocks is an image. I need to pull the src from the img of each of these blocks and apply them as the background for these blocks.

Here is my code

```
$('.Home-Jump-Wrap').each(function() {
    var bannerImage = $(this).find(".Jump-Image img").attr("src");
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(" + bannerImage + ")");
    $(".Jump-Image").closest(".row-fluid-wrapper").remove();
});
```

Right now this code works, only instead of applying the src of each img in each block (all images are different), it only does the first one. It removes the images from all of the blocks but the last three blocks' backgrounds are empty. any ideas?

Comment: Please share the html

Comment: with html code will be use full to find issue

Comment: Do you have some parent div containing all these four blocks?
Can you please share the HTML involved?

Comment: how to do this functionality same for angular js website for every page load this kind of functionality ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably issue is the way you are removing `.row-fluid-wrapper` elements.
Replace line

```
$(".Jump-Image").closest(".row-fluid-wrapper").remove();
```

to

```
$(this).find(".Jump-Image").closest(".row-fluid-wrapper").remove();
```

Comment: Oh wow Thanks! It's pretty obvious now but I was playing with the variable the whole time and wouldn't have done this. The code was removing the images on all of the blocks on the first run through so the images didn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

`$(".Jump-Image")` finds all elements with "Jump-Image" class starting from root of your document. Try to replace your `$(".Jump-Image").closest(".row-fluid-wrapper").remove();` with this one:

```
$(this).find(".Jump-Image").closest(".row-fluid-wrapper").remove();
```